# Cloud Functions migration: Beta to v1.0

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I had a go at updating the cloud function for my app by following the guide provided by Firebase but I'm not sure if I got it right. I've put below the before and after versions of my codes, could someone please advise if I'm missing anything?

```
//Beta Version of the code
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.countFrequency = functions.database.ref("country/{gameType}/combinationFrequencyCounter/{combinationLength}/{combinationId}/children").onWrite(event => {

    countRef = event.data.numChildren();
    key = 1000000000 - countRef;
    uniqueKey = key+"_"+event.params.combinationId;
    frequencyPushes = event.data.ref.parent.child('frequency').set(countRef);
    uniqueKeyPushes = event.data.adminRef.root.child("country/"+event.params.gameType+"/combinations/"+event.params.combinationLength+"/"+event.params.combinationId+"/uniqueKey").set(uniqueKey);
    frequency = event.data.adminRef.root.child("country/"+event.params.gameType+"/combinations/"+event.params.combinationLength+"/"+event.params.combinationId+"/frequency").set(countRef);

    return uniqueKeyPushes;

});

//v1.0 Version of the code
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.countFrequency = functions.database.ref("country/{gameType}/combinationFrequencyCounter/{combinationLength}/{combinationId}/children").onWrite((change, context) => {

    countRef = change.after.numChildren();
    key = 1000000000 - countRef;
    uniqueKey = key+"_"+context.params.combinationId;
    frequencyPushes = change.after.ref.parent.child('frequency').set(countRef);
    uniqueKeyPushes = change.after.ref.root.child("country/"+context.params.gameType+"/combinations/"+context.params.combinationLength+"/"+context.params.combinationId+"/uniqueKey").set(uniqueKey);
    frequency = change.after.ref.root.child("country/"+context.params.gameType+"/combinations/"+context.params.combinationLength+"/"+context.params.combinationId+"/frequency").set(countRef);

    return uniqueKeyPushes;

});
```

Also, what do I have to do after I update the code to v1.0? Do I simply upload the new function by using "firebase deploy --only functions" as I did during the Beta?

Comment: seems correct, yes just deploy normally `firebase deploy --only functions`

Comment: Please only ask a question on stack overflow if something isn't working the way you expect.